# How to get store config value in to javascript file

Tags: magento

In Magento i would like to test a condition based on a store config value but i would like to do the test inside a javascript file.

Is this possible?

Comment: The question is kind of nebulous. Is this javascript within a Magento page? Pseudocode can be as simple as <?php echo $this->getMageThing(); ?> within on page javascript where you want to insert the value or more complex if you're querying core_config. Please give more specific detail as to the store config value and where the javscript lives for a better answer.

Comment: Basically, i have a javascript file, not a phtml file or anything.  So the javascript file is being loaded via the head.  But in one of the functions in the script i need to check a value that can only come from store config.  I can therefore not work out how to inject that variable into the javascript file

Comment: You can `<script scr="some.php"></script>`.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest approach to handling this is to allow the configuration value to be passed to the script as a parameter or via a method call.  Then supply the parameter value from a template.  So for example, if your JavaScript file contains a JavaScript object, allow that object to accept the values you need from the Magento configuration via it's constructor or a "setConfigValue()" method call on that object.  Then instantiate the object and supply the parameters (or call the "setConfigValue()" method) in a template file.